# Why does this turn into a stack overflow?

Tags: rust, stack-overflow

Simple test case that fails with stack overflow:

```rust
// trait to say FnMut has a clone_box method
pub trait ClonableFnMut<A>: FnMut(A) {
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn ClonableFnMut<A> + Send + 'static>;
}

// overridden .clone() for Box<ClonableFnMut> that calls .clone_box on f
impl<A: 'static> Clone for Box<dyn ClonableFnMut<A> + Send + 'static> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        self.clone_box()
    }
}

// .clone_box() on FnMut clones itself and wraps itself in a new Box
impl<A, F: FnMut(A) + Clone + Send + 'static> ClonableFnMut<A> for F {
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn ClonableFnMut<A> + Send + 'static> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut f: Box<dyn ClonableFnMut<u8> + Send + 'static> = Box::new(|_x|{});

    println!("{:?}", f(3));
    println!("{:?}", f.clone()(4));
}
```

Theoretically:

1. Call `.clone()` on `Box<ClonableFnMut>`.
2. Custom implementation calls `.clone_box()` on the inner `FnMut`.
3. The inner `FnMut` can now call `.clone()` on itself, since it's marked Clone.
4. `.clone_box()` returns this cloned `FnMut` (self) in a new Box

But it actually:

1. calls `.clone()` manually on `Box<ClonableFnMut>`.
2. calls `.clone_box()` on inner `Box<FnMut>`.
3. calls `self.clone()` which appears to mean `self = box`.
4. custom `Box<FnMut>` `clone()` is called again, starts at step 1.

What's the actual reason for step 4 happening?

Comment: I think you have an issue on trying to clone `Box` that only implements `Clone` on types implementing `Clone` themselves, while you are trying to call clone on `FnMut`s which is impossible to clone. Because of this I think you are running into some `Deref`s kicking in, essentially cloning the types themselves (also, that would completely explaining your error, I think). I tried to put together a working example using `Fn`s, but I was unable to came up with a working example.

Comment: FnMut is possible to Clone as long as everything it contains is also Clone. The code here works with @Tanriol's suggested change of using **self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing happening actually is slightly different:

1. Someone calls `clone` on `Box`...
2. ...which calls `clone_box` on *the same `Box`*...
3. ...which calls `clone` on *the same `Box`* again, closing the loop.

This happens because your implementation of `Clone` calls just `self.clone_box()`, but `clone_box` is a method of the `ClonableFnMut` trait. This trait is implemented, in particular, on `Box<dyn ClonableFnMut<A> + Send + 'static>` due to the blanket implementation, the requirements of which `F: FnMut(A) + Clone + Send + 'static` are satisfied by the Box itself.

To avoid this, you need to force the `Clone` implementation to call the `clone_box` method for the contents of the `Box`, not for the `Box` itself. There are two obvious ways in slightly different styles:

1. [Replace](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bdfec1520f90fe2755bc5a9c8c88c1e7) `self.clone_box()` with `self.deref().clone_box()` and add the required import `use std::ops::Deref;` somewhere.
2. Alternatively, [replace](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dec1af0d93fed1e92428bd7a83a0f59d) `self.clone_box()` with `(**self).clone_box()`, which does not require an extra import, but looks slightly cryptic. Note that the argument of clone, `&self`, is basically a syntactic sugar for `self: &Self`, so the first `*` dereferences it from `&Box<F>` to `Box<F>` and the second one dereferences it once more to `F`. Calling `clone_box` then auto-references it to `&F` as it requires `&self` too.

Comment: Yep that was it, I just needed `(**self).clone_box()`. When I tried `(*self).clone_box()` earlier, I was forgetting self was actually `&self`, so it was just giving me the Box directly. Hence the recursion!